# What is the little dot/icon at the center of the screen in an FPS game called?

Tags: terminology, first-person-shooter

So I am developing a game and trying to find one of those to use, but I don't know what to search for. If you don't know what I am taking about, look at these examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What are these called?

Comment: Someone protected this so I can't post an answer. But an older term that refers specifically to dots on gunsights is [Tommy Dot](https://books.google.com/books?id=WyYDAAAAMBAJ&pg=RA1-PA216&lpg=RA1-PA216&dq=%22tommy+dot%22&source=bl&ots=NOyP78m5kd&sig=r2HXSstFJkydxkHUV69c-P9X__Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV9_uE8sDXAhVFOCYKHS0CDDQQ6AEIQTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22tommy%20dot%22&f=false). This probably won't help you though, because I doubt many video game designers use the term.

Comment: Why _was_ this protected? It feels a little odd that the presence of a single mediocre answer was enough to protect a question...

Comment: The pew pew hole

Answer (score 121, accepted):

"Crosshairs" or an "aiming [reticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reticle)," usually. Probably also "aiming dot" and similar variations.

Comment: Also spelled "reticule" (which, by delightful coincidence, also means a small ladies' handbag).

Comment: I've also seen the term "boresight" used for this

Comment: Also "targeting reticle".

Comment: I'm used to use 'crosshair' myself. But didn't knew that it's actually a subterm of the 'reticle'. interesting to know.

Answer (score 44):

In addition to what Josh Petrie mentioned: if you're looking for more advanced ways to aim weapons, the center dot in your bottom image is also called a "[pipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicted_impact_point)" in real-life applications.

This especially applies when some device is actively predicting where an arcing projectile will impact, like a bomb or grenade, instead of simply showing which direction it will go when fired/thrown/dropped.

Aircraft HUDs combine pippers and reticles to convey extra information about [complicated firing solutions](http://www.simhq.com/_air/air_101b.html), as shown in this example:

[image: Continuously Computed Impact Point Reticle]
*Continuously Computed Impact Point Reticle*

So in your third image, the circular arcs are the reticle, while the center dot is the pipper.

Answer (score -1):

That's usually called a crosshair. Also they're probably the easiest texture to make yourself, you don't need to find one online.

Comment: This adds nothing to the answers already posted.

Comment: It's simpler. Some of the other answers contained *more* information than requested, which could be confusing to readers. This answer only answers the question directly.

Comment: Please tell me how you answer is simpler than Josh Petrie's answer? It even contains more characters.

Comment: @Charanor It provides only one, most common, answer instead of two alternatives with speculation and an unnecessary link.

Comment: This is a place to come to be informed. Dumbing down answers to provide one interpretation of what you believe to be the "better" answer completely misses the point.

Comment: ... and if one is confused by the fact that more than one term exists that refers to the same thing, and the presence of a link, I'd imagine that person would have a couple more important issues to worry about.

Comment: "You don't need to find one online" is also very subjective. 
A basic, pixelated sprite is easy indeed. but making any of the HQ recticles can't be done with your basic paint program.